# Background pattern with Itext

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating a document wiht itext.

My iText Version is: itext-2.0.8

I need following final product: [image]

I have a PDF Table with 2 Columns.

I added a background color for each cell. But this is the outcome:

[image]

Is it possible to get the pattern from the first picture?

Some come sample:

```
private static Color firstBGColColor = new Color(255,222,166);
  ...
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setWidths(new float[]{160,400});
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setPaddingLeft(7);
cell.setPaddingTop(10);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setBackgroundColor(firstBGColColor);
```

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie maybe you could help me?

Comment: He probably won't since you are using an old iText version.

Comment: @Lonzak I don't see this as a reason why he and others would not help. I am at a point where I can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have not seriously worked with such an ancient iText version and, therefore, can only point to more current code. A quick look at the svn annotate results seems to indicate, though, that most of the central functionality has been present in iText for a long time. Thus, this code should at least show you how to get started.*

PDF knows the concept of a tiling pattern, confer section 8.7.3 *Tiling Patterns* of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), which should be what you need to create the proper background. iText supports such tiling patterns as demonstrated in the example [TilingPatternColor.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=179) using a helper method from [DeviceColor.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=177). An excerpt:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

PdfPatternPainter square = canvas.createPattern(15, 15);
square.setColorFill(new BaseColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00));
square.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));
square.rectangle(5, 5, 5, 5);
square.fillStroke();
```

Having defined a `PdfPatternPainter` like this, you can generate a color instance from it as `new PatternColor(square)` and use this color.

The samples uses it like this:

```
canvas.saveState();
canvas.setColorFill(new PatternColor(square));
canvas.rectangle(36, 696, 126, 126);
canvas.fillStroke();
canvas.restoreState();
```

You of course have to design your `PdfPatternPainter` differently. As it essentially is a `PdfTemplate`, though, you have all the means required to create any tiling pattern you want.